# Could not find default endpoint element that references contract... But application still works

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

I am currently working on a WPF Application, using a different project to call a WebService.
When I try to build i get this error:

> Could not find default endpoint element that references contract
>   'VisitorRegistrationWebService.VisitorRegistrationWebServiceSoap' in
>   the ServiceModel  client configuration section. This might be because
>   no configuration file was found for your application, or because no
>   endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client
>   element.

The app.config from my webservice project is just the same as the one from my WPF project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="VisitorRegistrationWebServiceSoap" />
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost/webservices/VisitorRegistrationWebService.asmx"
      binding="basicHttpBinding"   bindingConfiguration="VisitorRegistrationWebServiceSoap"
      contract="BasicVisitorRegistrationWebService.VisitorRegistrationWebServiceSoap"
      name="VisitorRegistrationWebServiceSoap" />
</client>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

The strange thing is that I can run the project and use the webservice to get data, but the error will not go away, no matter how many times I clean and rebuild my solution.

Comment: Delete the references and add it again

Comment: Thx for the reply but already tried that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in error message, contract name is 'VisitorRegistrationWebService.VisitorRegistrationWebServiceSoap'

and in endPoint configuration, contract="BasicVisitorRegistrationWebService.VisitorRegistrationWebServiceSoap"